# Make an Ajax request in Symfony2

Tags: ajax, symfony

My problem is that the method doesn't return a true result.
     I want to test if the email of input exists in my entity or not.

Here is the controller:

```
public function verificationAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($this->container->get('request')->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $email=$request->request->get('email');

        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $resp= $em->getRepository("CMSiteBundle:Prospect")->findBy(array('email'=>$email));
        $response =new Response(json_encode($resp));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try an old-trick. Since in Symfony Controller Actions, You must return a Response why not fake a DEAD RESPONSE like so:

```
    <?php

        class ABCController {

            public function verificationAction(Request $request) {
                if ($this->container->get('request')->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                    $email = $request->request->get('email');

                    $em       = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                    $resp     = $em->getRepository("CMSiteBundle:Prospect")
                                   ->findBy(array('email' => $email));
                    //$response = new Response(json_encode($resp));
                    //$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                    // THE TRICK IS THAT DIE RUNS FIRST 
                    // THUS SENDS YOUR RESPONSE YOU THEREBY
                    // STOPPING THE RETURN FROM FIRING... ;-)
                    return die(json_encode($resp));
                }
            }
        }
```

Perhaps this very Old Trick still works for you... ;-)